# Can I make a button in swift whose text has multiple colors?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring

Can I make a button in swift whose text has multiple colors? The button text will change dynamically, so I cannot make an image of it.

I have tried to make two attributed strings with different colors, concatenate them, and set the button's text to that. Unfortunately, that does not preserve the different colors and just adds plaintext describing the nsattribtues at the end of the string.

```
let currDescString = NSAttributedString(string: descriptor)
let editString = NSAttributedString(string: "(edit)", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()])
let editDescriptionString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(descriptor) \(editString)")
subBttn.setAttributedTitle(editDescriptionString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I want the currDescString to be black and the editString to be blue...In line 3 i try to concatenate those and in line 4 I try to set the title. Same problem as stated above persists.

Comment: You only need one `NSAttributedString`, set a range to one color, and another range to another color. Then set it as the button's title using `setAttributedTitle:forState:`.

Comment: Could you show the code you tried with the attributed string? It should have preserved the colors. You may have miss something.

Comment: I added the code and some more info to my original question above...please let me know if it helps your analysis

Comment: Your issue was with the construction of `editDescriptionString`. That's normal it didn't work. You created it with string, instead of the previous attributedString (which contains colors and others render effects). You should have append them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this:

```
let att = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello!");
att.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 2))
att.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location: 2, length: 2))
button.setAttributedTitle(att, forState: .Normal)
```

You can use the range parameter of addAttribute method to specify which color that substring should have.

And for your example this is something like this:

```
let string1 = "..."
let string2 = "..."

let att = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(string1)\(string2)");
att.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string1.characters.count))
att.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location: string1.characters.count, length: string2.characters.count))
button.setAttributedTitle(att, forState: .Normal)
```